# Jacobian basics question - Show and explain why J(u, v) = ∂(x, y)/ ∂(u, v) = (∂(u, v) ∂(x, y))^(−1)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

I am stuck on a question in my calc III class which is shown in the link below (part a). I completely understand how to find the Jacobian; however I don't understand why the relationship shown is true. I have searched for hours for an answer to this but cannot seem to find one.

In terms of the Jacobian, I got $$J = \frac{1}{2u}$$.

Thanks for your time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq2ya.png

Answer (score 0):

Hint. As regards (a), note that $x(u(x,y),v(x,y))=x$ and $y(u(x,y),v(x,y))=y$.
Hence, by taking the derivative with respect to $x$ of both sides of  $x(u(x,y),v(x,y))=x$, by the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions) we get
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+
\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=1.$$
On the other hand, the derivative with respect to $y$ of $x(u(x,y),v(x,y))=x$ yields
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+
\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm quite confused. Where did those equations come from? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Daniel Lowton I'm applying the chain rule to the identity $x(u(x,y),v(x,y))=x$.